# What is the best practice for complex filtering in React Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

So I've been doing some research on more complex filters using React Redux, and I can't seem to find an answer to my problem. I have two solutions that work, but they're kinda messy and I'm not sure if my solution the best way to do it. I have recently learned the Redux toolkit syntax with using createSlice and such, and so I've found the createSelector to work nicely in both situations.

**solution 1: filtering all the data using one multiple filters across multiple createSelectors**

critterSlice.js

```
export const selectCritters = (state, critter) => state.critters[critter]

 // selectLanguage comes from a userSlice, its result is "USen"
const searchFilterSelector = createSelector(
    [selectCritters, selectLanguage, selectFilters],
    (critterArr, lang, filters) => critterArr.filter(critter => critter.name[`name-${lang}`].toUpperCase().includes(filters.searchText.toUpperCase()))
)

const timeOfYearFilterSelector = createSelector(
    [searchFilterSelector, selectFilters],
    (searchFilteredCritterArr, filters) => searchFilteredCritterArr.filter(critter => {
           const {isAllYearChecked, selectedMonths} = filters
           const {availability} = critter
           
            return isAllYearChecked ? true
                : selectedMonths.length === 0 ? false
                : availability.isAllYear ? true
                : availability[`month-array-${filters.hemisphere}`].some(month => selectedMonths.includes(month))
        }
    )
)

//# for timeOfDayFilterSelector
const range = (min, max) => {
    const arr = []
    while (min <= max) {
        arr.push(min++)
    }
    return arr
}

const timeOfDayFilterSelector = createSelector(
    [timeOfYearFilterSelector, selectFilters],
    (timeOfYearFilteredCritterArr, filters) => (
        timeOfYearFilteredCritterArr.filter(critter => {
            const {availability} = critter
            const {timeOfDay} = filters

            return availability.isAllDay ? true
                : availability["time-array"].some(time => range(timeOfDay.min, timeOfDay.max).includes(time))
        })
    )
)
```

filtersSlice.js

```
    const currentMonth = new Date().getMonth() + 1
    
    const initialState = {
        searchText: "",
    
        hemisphere: "northern",
        isAllYearChecked: false,
        selectedMonths: [currentMonth],
    
        timeOfDay: {min: 0, max: 24},
    
        sellPrice: {min: 0, max: 12000}
    }
    
    // omit filterSlice
    
    export const selectFilters = state => state.filters
```

**solution 2: putting all the filters in one filter method**

```
    export const allFiltersSelector = createSelector(
        [selectCritters, selectLanguage, selectFilters],
        (critterArr, lang, filters) => critterArr.filter(critter => {
            const {name, price: critterPrice, availability} = critter
            const {isAllYearChecked, selectedMonths, sellPrice, searchText, hemisphere, timeOfDay} = filters
    
            return (
                //# Month filter
                // checks what months the critter is available by comparing both arrays
                (isAllYearChecked ? true
                    : selectedMonths.length === 0 ? false
                    : availability.isAllYear ? true
                    : availability[`month-array-${hemisphere}`].some(month => selectedMonths.includes(month)))
    
                //# Time of day filter
                // checks what time the critter is available by comparing both arrays
                && (availability.isAllDay ? true
                    : availability["time-array"].some(time => range(timeOfDay.min, timeOfDay.max).includes(time)))
                    
                //# Price filter
                // checks to make sure the price is between or equal to the selected prices
                && (critterPrice >= sellPrice.min && critterPrice <= sellPrice.max)
    
                //# Search filter
                // for the search bar to work
                && name[`name-${lang}`].toUpperCase().includes(searchText.toUpperCase())
            )
        })
    )

    // omit filtersSlice.js
```

Combining all the filters into one filter requires much less code, but is that bad practice? It's not super readable, so if that is the better way, can I improve my code to be cleaner? I'm still relatively new to redux and this is my first time implementing filters, so any help would be great! Thanks for taking the time to read my post!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make each condition a function with clear name
Then create a simple to read high-level filter

```
const result = isYellow(critter) && isBig(critter) && isFast(critter)
```

or

```
 arr.filter(isYellow).filter(isBig).filter(isFast)
```

If this is slow, then do

```
 arr.filter((c)=>isYellow(c) && isBig(c) && isFast(c));
```

having a clear, reusable filter components makes the code readable, and easier to change.